# Remote backup solution for openSuSE

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, backup, opensuse

I'm looking for some backup solution. My request is pretty simple:

- **Source** - FTP credentials (ftp://user:pass@server.tld/dir1/dir2)
- **Destination** on local HDD (/var/backup/server-tld)
- Possibility of packing to **archive** (tar.gz/zip)
- Plan this "script" as a **cron job** with defined period (e.g. once a day)

I know, that **all this can be done using bash scripts**, but it seems to be a little bit uncomfortable.

I don't believe there's no simple solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a really "simple-to-use" solution:

**ncftp**

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-download-all-file-from-ftp-server-recursively.html